# Multi thread server can not read messages from clients in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

Trying to implement a multi thread server in Qt, just consider this:
**in SocketThread class:**

```
SocketThread::SocketThread(qintptr descriptor, QObject *parent)
    : QThread(parent), socketDescriptor(descriptor)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket();
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);

    socket->moveToThread(this);

    connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, [this]() { qDebug() << socket->readAll(); }); //trying to read messages from clients
}
```

**in Connection class:** *creating thread in `incomingConnection()`*

```
void Connection::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    SocketThread *socketThread = new SocketThread(socketDescriptor);
    socketThread->start();

    connect(socketThread, &SocketThread::started, [&]() { socketThread->socket->write("Hello!"); });  //write a message to client when thread is created
}
```

Strange thing is, if I add this line:

> connect(socketThread, &SocketThread::started, & { socketThread->socket->write("Hello!"); });  //write a message to client when thread is created

Then the socket will not read message from client. If I remove that line, the socket will read message from client.
I want the server to send message to client when a thread is created and to read message from client as well. How can do solve the problem?

**Edit:**

**SocketThread header file:**

```
class SocketThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SocketThread(qintptr descriptor, QObject *parent = 0);
    ~SocketThread();
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    qintptr socketDescriptor;
};
```

**in the Connection constructor:**

```
Connection::Connection(QObject *parent) : QTcpServer(parent)
{
    this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 6666);
}
```

And creating a connection object in the `main.cpp` file. That's really like all the code.

Comment: Possibly unrelated but... why are you calling `socketThread->start()` *before* connecting anything to the `QThread::started` signal?

Comment: @G.M. Don't know if there is a different between calling `socketThread->start()` before `started` signal and after `started` signal.

Comment: @TheodoreTang provide a [mcve] :)

Comment: @eyllanesc hmm... I think I did provide a minimal example. That's almost everything of my code. Except I didn't provide the `SocketThread` header file, which just have a `QTcpSocket` pointer and a `socketDescriptor` in it. And in the `Connection` constructor, I just start the server to listen. That's it. Anything else that I should add into my question?

Comment: @TheodoreTang hmm... 
No, it is not verifiable and complete, if it were complete it would be enough to copy your code and then reproduce your problem, but clearly I can not do it, a program is not 2 functions out of context.

Comment: @eyllanesc How about now? I almost put all the code, except the `connection` header file, which just has a `void incomingConnection(qintptr);` function. Does my edit help?

Comment: @TheodoreTang 
no, it is not, it shows the complete code of both classes and the main.

Comment: @eyllanesc But my code just has two classes which I provided, and a main file which just has a `connection` object in it. Don't know why you think that's incomplete. I will create a GitHub repo to send that to you, if that helps?

Comment: If you call `socketThread->start()` before connecting to the `QThread::started` signal I don't think there's any guarantee that you'll catch the signal.

Comment: I do not see the 2 full classes, so I presume there may be more code.

Comment: @eyllanesc https://github.com/elvisxiaozhi/Stack-Overflow-Question , Just pushed the code to github.

Comment: @G.M. It does catch the signal even if you start the thread before `started` signal. But thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: @TheodoreTang
It does not read because the program closes immediately, at least that happens in my test

Comment: @eyllanesc well, that's really confusing. With the same code, my program doesn't close immediately. It still opens for listening, you can still connect to the sever. It just won't read messages from clients.

Comment: @eyllanesc Did you try to comment out that line? Then it will read messages successfully from clients. I don't really know what is going on there.

Comment: if you comment `socketThread->socket->write("Hello!");` the connection is still maintained, so I think that socketThread in that part is the problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc Can you help with that? I really tried everything I could, just couldn't find where the problem is. I even tried not to use a multi thread on server, then  read and send message will both work. Maybe something's gone wrong in the `socketThread`

Comment: @TheodoreTang Why do you have the need to use threads? Is your processing heavy? Qt sockets can work through signals without problems, it would be justifiable if you are only going to do a heavy task.

Comment: @eyllanesc I don't have to use threads. But I am just learning how to use multi threads, so I just tried to use multi thread for each socket, thought that should be a right way to do.

Comment: @TheodoreTang see this: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTcpServer_Multithreaded_Client_Server.php

Comment: @eyllanesc I just tested the link's code. And I found out it has the same problem, that if I add this line `connect(this, &MyThread::started, [this](){ socket->write("Hello"); });`, then the program will just not send or read messages anymore. Do you know why this will happen? Which means my code probably has the right multi threads, just somehow that line causes the program to work properly.

Comment: @TheodoreTang 
The problem is simple, the QObjects can only be executed in the thread they belong to, `socket` belongs to a secondary thread and you are using it in the main thread.

Comment: @eyllanesc I don't think that is where the problem is. I also tested using the socket in its thread, not the main thread, but the problem is still there. Now I am just wondering how to send a message to clients when a thread is created. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @TheodoreTang the QThread is not a thread, it is a thread handler (read the documentation), only the run() method is the part that belongs to that thread.